# Serializing multiple OneToMany Collections to JSON in Java Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a problem with JSON serializing of an object. The object is built correctly (I"ve debugged it and all the data is there, but it's not serialized as it should be).

**Student class**

```
public class Student extends AbstractUser {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ActivityAttendance.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<ActivityAttendance> attendances;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ActivityGrade.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<ActivityGrade> grades;

    ...
}
```

**Custom Student Serializer** (used by the ActivityAttendance, ActivityGrade classes to remove the infinite recursion)

```
public class CustomStudentSerializer extends StdSerializer<Student> {

...

@Override
public void serialize(
        Student student,
        JsonGenerator generator,
        SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ...
        student.setAttendances(null);
        student.setGrades(null);
        ...

        generator.writeObject(student);
    }
}
```

Here I remove the Attendance/Grades of students properties contained by the ActivityAttendance, ActivityGrade objects.

However the **JSON output** is always returning results for only one of the two collections. The grades field should contain a list of objects as well, but it always returns **null**.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "test",
  "lastName": "test",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "attendances": [
    {
      "id": {},
      "student": {
        ...
      },
      "activity": {
        ...
      }
    }
  ],
  "grades": null
}
```

I want the grades field to display the elements as well. In the controller the object has all the data.

If I remove the attendances field, the grades will display correctly. Do you have any idea what causes this and how I can solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DTOs` to avoid infinite recursion. Basically the `DTO` should have the same fields (without `id`) and let `Jackson` do the serialization for you.
When you return your `Object` via `Controller` just implement a method in your `Entity` or `Controller` that transforms your `Entity` into `EntityDTO` (with `ObjectMapper` or `getters & setters`) 
Ex:

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity getStudent(@PathParam("firstName")String firstName){
    studentRepository.findStudentByFirstName(firstName).toDTO();
}
```

Url might look like `localhost:8080/students/firstName`

I tried it myself and I had no problems with 2 `lists`

Comment: I've mapped the Student to StudentDto with ModelMapper in the controller and now it works as it should. I still don't understand why it works like this (since it's pretty much the same object without annotations) but it's a good workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. Keep that in mind, you should never return an `Entity` via `GET` or `POST`. In my opinion this is the right way to do it and a lot cleaner and easier.